# Craft 3 How to get custom user field values

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, users

I have following custom fields for users.

```
favouriteEntries - 'entry' type field with multiple entries per user
notificationPreference - Lightswitch field
```

My plugin should email notifications to users who follow that entry when there is an update to a particular entry (`Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE`).

```
use craft\elements\User;

$users = User::find()->all();
```

With the above code, I can get all user data including `notificationPreference` but `favouriteEntries`. `favouriteEntries` field returns `null` even if it has entries for all users.

What's the correct way to get all user data including `favouriteEntries` field?

Comment: `favouriteEntries` should never ever return null in no case since it will always contain an object of type `ElementQuery`. Could you eventually show your entire code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to access the custom fields on element\user object.

```PHP
Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->getFieldValue('customfieldname');
```

Comment: What about in twig?

Answer (score 5):

If someone lands here searching for a Twig answer like me.

```
{{ currentUser.customFieldHandle }}
```